# Email Client doesn't open attachment but will download and open

Tags: php, email, email-client, email-attachments, email-headers

I'm using PHP to send an attachment in an email, all works as expected except in the email client (with other email attachments) I can just click on it and it would launch the external application to view the file, or at least give me an option to select a program to try and view it. I'm not getting this as nothing happens when I click on the attachment. I can download it and view it and that works as expect.

Wanted to know if I'm missing something in the header.

Here is my function (it's in a class):

```
public function mail() {
    if(!empty($this->attachment)) {
        $filename   = empty($this->attachment_filename) ? basename($this->attachment) : $this->attachment_filename;
        $path       = dirname($this->attachment);
        $mailto     = $this->to;
        $from_mail  = $this->from;
        $from_name  = $this->from_name;
        $replyto    = $this->reply_to;
        $subject    = $this->subject;
        $message    = $this->message;

        $file       = $path.'/'.$filename;
        $file_size  = filesize($file);
        $handle     = fopen($file, "r");
        $content    = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $content    = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        $uid        = md5(uniqid(time()));
        $name       = basename($file);

        $mime_type  = $this->getMimeType($file); // function returns the MIME type

        $header  = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
        $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: ".$mime_type."; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."--";

        return (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header) ? true : false);
    } else {
        $header  = "From: ".($this->from_name)." <".($this->from).">\r\n";
        $header .= "Reply-To: ".($this->reply_to)."\r\n";

        return (mail($this->to, $this->subject, $this->message, $header) ? true : false);
    }
}
```

How I'm calling it (which works and send the email w/ the attachment as expected)

```
$sendit = new MailAttachment(
    $to, 
    $subject, 
    $message, 
    $excel_report,
    basename($excel_report)
);

if(!$sendit->mail()) {
    return 'Error';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried another email program? other software might give you an error message if something is wrong.

Comment: yes on Mac (mail) and Linux (Thunderbird) nothing looks wrong in the client just won't open when double clicking, have to download to view content

Comment: If the attachment that comes in your email message is downloadable, then the issue is not PHP related. Maybe you have some Security setting in your email client that prohibits you from opening/running attachments?

Comment: I don't think it's PHP but maybe something in the header, the client is fine as other emails with attachments work just fine

Comment: You could try SwiftMailer. It's pretty easy to get going (especially since you're already sending email successfully) then you can compare the headers. http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Just wanted to know if the header was at fault, I know I could use an alternative service but it's 99% working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out everything is working as expected. The issue with the mail client is the file extension.

- The file(s) with the extension .xls open up on double click from the email client,
- The file(s) with the extension .xlsx do not open up on double click from the email client and need to be downloaded and opened.

Hope this helps someone out.